# NullPointerException when using OmniFaces' of:printStackTrace

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm using OmniFaces to show a nice and detailed error page, just like [this one](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) from the showcase.

Here is my error page:

```
<ui:composition template="#{erroMB.layout}">
    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <p:panel collapsed="true" toggleable="true"
            header="Desculpe-nos, um erro ocorreu.">
            <ul style="font-size: 1em; margin-left: 10px;">
                <li>Date/time: #{of:formatDate(now, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}</li>
                <li>User agent: #{header['user-agent']}</li>
                <li>User IP: #{request.remoteAddr}</li>
                <li>Request URI: #requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}</li>
                <li>Ajax request: #{facesContext.partialViewContext.ajaxRequest ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}</li>
                <li>Status code: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}</li>
                <li>Exception type: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception_type']}</li>
                <li>Exception message: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}</li>
                <li>Stack trace: <pre>#{of:printStackTrace(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'])}</pre>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p:panel>
        <h:outputScript rendered="#{facesContext.partialViewContext.ajaxRequest}">scrollTo(0, 0);</h:outputScript>

        <br />
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Voltar para Início"
                action="#{navegacaoPesquisaMB.irPesquisa()}" ajax="false"
                style="width: 100%;" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The page renders nicely, but when I click on the `p:commandButton` at the end of the page, I get a NullPointerException at `of:printStackTrace`. I can't understand why this happens, since the function was already called and printed it's result. I can't see why JSF is trying to call the function again, and even stranger, when I click on a button that is inside *another* form.

Full Stack Trace of when I click the commandButton:

```
14:00:57,404 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Error Rendering View[/erro.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /erro.xhtml: Problems calling function 'of:printStackTrace'
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:198) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:115) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUrlPattern.doFilter(FiltroUrlPattern.java:50) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:22) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.el.functions.Converters.printStackTrace(Converters.java:97) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:112) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 51 more

14:00:57,410 WARN  [org.jboss.solder.exception.control.log] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) No handlers found for exception javax.el.ELException: /erro.xhtml: Problems calling function 'of:printStackTrace'
14:00:57,411 WARN  [org.jboss.solder.exception.control.log] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) No handlers found for exception javax.servlet.ServletException
14:00:57,412 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/pso].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:343) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:162) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:554) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUrlPattern.doFilter(FiltroUrlPattern.java:50) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:22) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.el.functions.Converters.printStackTrace(Converters.java:97) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:112) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:198) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:115) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, the form is apparently synchronously submitting to self, so the page is redisplayed, so all EL expressions are evaluated again, but the exception is not available anymore in the scope.

Perhaps you want to remove `ajax="false"` and update only the part which really needs to be updated, or you perhaps you should actually be navigating to the target page?

```
<p:button value="Voltar para Início" outcome="/pesquisa.xhtml" style="width: 100%;" />
```

The `NullPointerException` is in turn indeed a bug in `of:printStackTrace()`. It's fixed since OmniFaces version 1.2.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about using `p:button`, although I have never used a EL expression in `outcome` (I have all my pages as String constants inside `NavegacaoPesquisaMB`). I'll try asap. Apart form that, can you elaborate on the *"synchronously submitting to self"* part? Or link me some explanation about that?

Comment: The EL expression in outcome would be evaluated as string during render time, exactly like output text. As to "synchronously submitting to self", I mean a normal postback. Like `<form method="post">` returning to the very same page, without using ajax.

Comment: But, is that supposed to happen? Shouldn't the `commandButton` navigate to the action's returned String, instead of doing a postback? Thank you.

Comment: That's just the way how stuff works. The `<h:commandButton>` generates a HTML `<input type="submit">`. When enclosed in a HTML `<form method="post" action="sameurl">` (as generated by `<h:form>`) then it does just a postback to the same page. That's just what your JSF code has generated. All you needed to do is to let it generate different HTML, achieving exactly the requirement you had in mind.

Comment: I see. It makes sense for me now. Thanks a lot for the explanation and for your time. :)